# Angular 6 Laravel 5.5: Radio Button Values not Submitted

Tags: html, angular, laravel, typescript

I created a small CRUD application using Angular and Laravel 5.5. In the application, I have three radio buttons and when I try to get the values of them, I get the error...

> Type error saying it cannot read the type of data

Below are the relevant parts of my scripts...

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label f class="col-sm-5 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Can you get over unsound mind?
        <span class="req">*</span>

    </label>
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">
        <input type="radio" name="unsound" [(ngModel)]="userDetails.isUnsoundMind" [value]="false"/>
        <span> No</span>
    </label>
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">
        <input type="radio" name="unsound" [(ngModel)]="userDetails.isUnsoundMind" [value]="true"/>
        <span> Yes</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
constructor(public data: DataService,private userService: UserService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private iNcoreService: IncorporationService, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

userDataSubmit() {

const data = {
  ....
  isUnsoundMind: this.userDetails['isUnsoundMind'],
  ....
};
console.log(data);
this.userService.userDataSubmit(data)
  .subscribe(
    req => {
      console.log("successful");
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

**Model**

```
export interface IUserData {
    ...
    isUnsoundMind: string;
    ...
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { APIConnection } from './connections/APIConnection';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IUserData } from '../models/user.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  url: APIConnection = new APIConnection();

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  userDataSubmit(data: IUserData): Observable<IUserData> {
    return this.http.post<IUserData>(this.url.getUserDataSubmit(), data);
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\v1\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Address;
use App\User;
use Storage;
use App;
use URL;
use App\Http\Helper\_helper;

class useritorController extends Controller
{
    use _helper;

    public function saveuserData(Request $request)
    {
        $userAddress = new Address();
        $userAddress->address1 = $request->input('localAddress1');

        $userinfo = new user();
        $userinfo->is_unsound_mind = $request->input('isUnsoundMind');
        $userinfo->save();
    }
}
```

As far as I'm concerned, there's no such error in all the above scripts, but every time I try to add the data to the DB it gives the above error, Some say when we add the radio button there's a small chunk of code to be written in the TS script, but no forum gives a proper explanation about it. Can someone help me out on this or give me proper guidance on how to add a radio button data to the DB table using Angular 6 + Laravel 5.5?

Comment: Any angular laraval expert please ??

Comment: As it's a typescript error, this should be related to angular code only and not laravel. Would you please provide the exact error? And in which browser are you getting this error. Also a more complete code of your typescript

Answer (score 0):

in typescript code you have defined data. try to define data as follows and see if its work:

```
 const data:IUserData = {
  isUnsoundMind: this.userDetails['isUnsoundMind']
 };
```

Comment: thank you for the reply mate, but it dint make any improvement in the code.. sorry